# Partitioning of variance

Tags: variance

Why do Mathematicians like to think about partitioning variances into different components -- the basis of ANOVA? In contrast, why is it not correct to partition the SD into components?

Answer (score 2):

Variances add up, when you add two independent variables, while the standard deviation does not. i.e. $Var(x+y) = Var(x) + Var(y)$ , if $x$ and $y$ are independent. This means that if you take a sample, and $x_1, ... , x_k$ are independent, then the variance of the mean is the mean of the variances of the variables. 
For the standard deviation, this is not true.